# Python webscraping. Trying to get autoplay position of video

Tags: javascript, python

I am writing a Python scraper for videos from pages like this:

http://www.europarl.europa.eu/plenary/NL/vod.html?mode=unit&vodLanguage=EN&startTime=20140414-20:11:06-421#

I want to get the start and end times of the speaker in question within the embedded video, but the listed start times do not correspond with the position in the video you end up at when you click on the button. In the link above, the listed time is 20:11:01, but it takes you to about 55:36 in the video.

I've been looking through the JS executed when you click the "Start of speaking time" button, but I can't figure out how that time is translated to where it takes you in the video.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Comment: are you using selenium for this?

Comment: In the page source search for `currentUnit.startSecondsIsma` , on the above link it is  `currentUnit.startSecondsIsma = "3336";` . So it is `3336 seconds` convert to  minutes `3336/60` and voila you get `55.6`
`